# Issue regarding deployment of android games on different screen sizes made in unity

Tags: android-layout, unity-game-engine

AOA,

I am developing game in Unity. My Basic Idea to develop is for Web, Standalone (PC & Mac) and for Android.
The major Problem I am having is that I am focusing to develop just for Android Right Now.
But I am totally unable to do anything. as when I change my whole script to meet a particular resolution. It's looks fine and works perfectly. Even in Android Remote it works fine on Device. But when I debug and run the app on Android device. Everything became so weird.
Kindly help me out.
If I make app for 1280x720 resolution which is of my device.
What is the surety that I'll still run fine for other devices with different resolution, for tablets and low end devices etc.

Kindly help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this thread, might help you with your problem.

[How to show the same part of game on every aspect ratio on Android devices with Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269453/how-to-show-the-same-part-of-game-on-every-aspect-ratio-on-android-devices-with/22316615#22316615)